# How can I increase the number of files remembered by GIMP?

Tags: gimp

As of now, GIMP 2.8 remembers just ten recent works in the "File"->"Open Recent" Menu. Is there any way to increase this number?
I did it in Gedit and I think it's possible in GIMP too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, just go here:
[image: 'Open Recent' > 'Document History']
<sup>For some reason, all of my recent history in Gimp does not seem to show... I had to copy a few files to get enough</sup>

Then you can view it in this dialogue - it shows more than 10:
[image]

For some reason I think it is limited so the keyboard short-cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> can be used.

---

### Edit:

I knew that `~/.gimp-2.8/gimprc` was the config file for GIMP - it had these lines:

```
# This is your personal gimprc file.  Any variable defined in this file takes
# precedence over the value defined in the system-wide gimprc:
# /etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc
```

So I looked in `/etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc` and found:

```
# How many recently opened image filenames to keep on the File menu.  This is
# an integer value.
# 
# (last-opened-size 10)
```

So simply add this line to your `~/.gimp-2.8/gimprc` file:

```
(last-opened-size 15)
```

To change the displayed history size to `15` for example.

Comment: I knew about the recent documents dialog but I wanted to do that in the menu so I can quickly open them using the HUD.

Comment: Dunno - I would like to know, sometimes my GIMP history is remembered....

Comment: Oooh... found something - that was quick...

Comment: Since you were the first one, let me accept your answer and upvote the other one "No hard feelings".

Answer (score 4):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc
```

Find this section:

```
# How many recently opened image filenames to keep on the File menu.  This is
# an integer value.
# 
#(last-opened-size 10)
```

Change it to:

```
# How many recently opened image filenames to keep on the File menu.  This is
# an integer value.
# 
(last-opened-size 20)
```

Or whatever number you prefer, if not 20. Proofread, save and close gedit. Close and reopen GIMP for the change to take effect.

Comment: Errr... Ooops... Sorry... +1